# Why can't I change the input field value in React?

Tags: reactjs

The current problem I am having is that after retrieving and setting the value, I am not able to edit the value in the input field after retrieving it. The value seems to be static and uneditable in the input field.

I want have to have flexibility to change the input field value even after retrieving the value.

Below is just a snippet of my code as to post the entire code is very large. I believe the problem lies  inside the `render()` where i set the `value={something}` and `handleInputChange`.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        seedURL: '',
        response: null,
        error: null, 
        loading: false
    };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
}

handleInputChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let name = e.target.name;
    let value = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
};



render() {
    const name = this.state.response ? this.state.response.data.name : "";
    const image = this.state.response ? this.state.response.data.image : "";

    return(
        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Business Name" name="name" onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={name} />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Image URL" name="image" onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={image} />
        </form>
    );
}
```

Comment: the value on your input field and the one you are setting in `handleInputChange` are different from one another

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for your response. I appreciate it. May I ask, how do I edit the `handleInputChange` above to make it editable?

Answer (score 1):

name and image are not defined in the state of your component.

```
 this.state = {
        seedURL: '',
        response: null,
        error: null, 
        loading: false
    };
```

You could add them, e.g

```
 this.state = {
        seedURL: '',
        response: null,
        error: null, 
        loading: false,
        image: '',
        name: ''
    };
```

But you will have to bind to this properties in the inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Business Name" name="name" onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={this.state.name} />
```

Alternatively, if you want to change the value of your response property of the state then you could use the spread operator to set the state of this object.

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  response: {
    ...this.state.response,
    data: {
      ...this.state.response.data,
      [name]: e.target.value
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi there! Sorry I'm trying to follow up, do correct me if im wrong. So the code remains the same except that I have to specify name and image in the state and bind in the input. Also, i copied the `setState` code and does not seem to work. I'm having a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null`.

Comment: No I'm not trying to make it my own. Im just trying to understand as im new to this.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're setting the `value` of `input` but that value is not changing when you type, to change those values you'll have to modify your `setState()` call to this:

```
this.setState({
  response: {
    ...this.state.response,
    data: {
      ...this.state.response.data,
      [name]: [value]
    }
  }
})
```

Hope this helps :)